# Do the columns of the distribution of the DenertMaxDifference statistic on permutations eventually become constant?

Tags: permutations

The well known Denert statistic on permutations $p$ of $[n]$ can be defined as the number of *Denert pairs*  for $p$, namely, the number of pairs $(i,j)$ with $1\le i<j\le n$ and
$j \in [p_i,p_j-1]$ if $p_i < p_j$ while $j \notin [p_j,p_i-1]$
if $p_j < p_i$. For example, the set of Denert pairs for $25134$ is **{**$(1,2), (1,3), (2,5)$**}** where, for example, $(1,3)$ qualifies because $3 \notin [p_3,p_1-1] = [1,1]$. The Denert pair set is empty only for the identity permutation.

Define the DenertMaxDifference statistic on $p$ to be the maximum difference of a Denert pair for $p$, taken to be $0$ if the Denert pair set is empty. For example, DenertMaxDifference($25134) = \max(2-1,3-1,5-2) =  3$. The distribution of DenertMaxDifference begins

1

1  1

1  2   3

1  2   9   12

1  2  14   43    60

1  2  14   93   250    360

1  2  14  136   657   1710    2520

1  2  14  136  1287   5280   13440   20160

Do the columns eventually become constant: 1, 2, 14, 136, ... ? If so, what is the nth term of the resulting sequence?

Comment: You might try your luck at https://www.findstat.org/